# GPO not applied, gpresult /R OK -- scheduled task not created

Tags: group-policy, scheduled-task

I've made a GPO that make a scheduled task.
This scheduled task access to a network share to execute a powershell program that will delete some mails in outlook.
Script is OK.

It's a User GPO.
[image]

When i launch a gpupdate /force, scheduled task does not appears but the GPO appears to be executed in gpresult /R.
It works only when i connect to computer with a user that have admin rights on computer.

id 4098
element user GPO was not applied because or error 0x80070005 acces denied.

Here the entire error message (in french)
[image]

Any idea?
thank.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, **the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: Removed my downvote. This is a lot better. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue.

Used this : 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2447414/user-gpp-scheduled-task-item-fails-to-apply-and-logs-event-id-4098-with-0x80070005-access-is-denied.

> To avoid this issue, do not enable the "Run in logged-on user’s
>   security context (user policy option)” Common option when configuring
>   user GPP Scheduled Tasks items.
>
> The security context under which the Scheduled Task will run once it
>   has been deployed can be specified in the General settings tab when
>   creating the User GPP Scheduled Task item:
>
> User Configuration\Preferences\Control Panel Settings\Scheduled
>   Tasks\New\"Scheduled Task (Windows Vista and later)"
>
> General:
>
> Security Options -> "When running the task, use the following user
>   account:"
>
> By default, this is set to: %LogonDomain%\%LogonUser%
>
> This is where the security context under which the scheduled task will
>   run should be configured.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the solution. Dont forget to mark your answer as accepted too please, as you can without problem. et bonne fin de journée :P